# Under windows cmake install libTorch-cpu to run error problem

Tags: cmake, clion, libtorch

**Why did I report an error as soon as I introduced libTorch, I tried it many times, please help me to see what's going on. Thank you**

I tried debug version and Release version based on CPU, this error always exists;

My CmakeLists.txt：

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
    project(Demo3)
    
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
    set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "K:/Qt/Qt5.12.10/5.12.10/msvc2017_64")
    set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
    
    set(QT_VERSION 5)
    set(REQUIRED_LIBS Core Gui Widgets)
    set(REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets)
    
    
    ############ add  libTorch ####################
    set(Torch_DIR K:\\pytorchModel\\libtorch\\share\\cmake\\Torch)
    find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
    include_directories(K:\\pytorchModel\\libtorch\\include K:\\pytorchModel\\libtorch\\include\\torch\\csrc\\api\\include\\torch)
    
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
    
    target_link_libraries(Demo3 "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
    
    
    if (NOT CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
        message(WARNING "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is not defined, you may need to set it "
                "(-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=\"path/to/Qt/lib/cmake\" or -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/include/{host}/qt{version}/ on Ubuntu)")
    endif ()
    
    find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION} COMPONENTS ${REQUIRED_LIBS} REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED})
    if (WIN32)
        set(DEBUG_SUFFIX)
        if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
            set(DEBUG_SUFFIX "d")
        endif ()
        set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
        if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
            set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
            if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
                set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
            endif ()
        endif ()
        if (EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll")
            add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory
                    "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
            add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                    "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                    "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
        endif ()
        foreach (QT_LIB ${REQUIRED_LIBS})
            add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                    "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin/Qt${QT_VERSION}${QT_LIB}${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                    "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>")
        endforeach (QT_LIB)
    endif ()
```

**The error after I run:**

```
main.cpp
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\c10/macros/Macros.h(189): warning C4067: 预处理器指令后有意外标记 - 应输入换行符
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(181): warning C4624: “c10::constexpr_storage_t<T>”: 已将析构函数隐式定义为“已删除”
        with
        [
            T=at::Tensor
        ]
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(361): note: 查看对正在编译的 类 模板 实例化“c10::constexpr_storage_t<T>”的引用
        with
        [
            T=at::Tensor
        ]
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(418): note: 查看对正在编译的 类 模板 实例化“c10::trivially_copyable_optimization_optional_base<T>”的引用
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::vector<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent,std::allocator<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent>>,std::allocator<std::vector<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent,std::allocator<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent>>>>
        ]
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(361): note: 查看对正在编译的 类 模板 实例化“c10::constexpr_storage_t<T>”的引用
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::vector<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent,std::allocator<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent>>,std::allocator<std::vector<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent,std::allocator<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent>>>>
        ]
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(418): note: 查看对正在编译的 类 模板 实例化“c10::trivially_copyable_optimization_optional_base<T>”的引用
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::vector<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent,std::allocator<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent>>,std::allocator<std::vector<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent,std::allocator<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent>>>>
        ]
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(418): note: 查看对正在编译的 别名 模板 实例化“c10::OptionalBase<std::vector<std::vector<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent,std::allocator<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent>>,std::allocator<std::vector<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent,std::allocator<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent>>>>>”的引用
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\torch/csrc/autograd/profiler_legacy.h(562): note: 查看对正在编译的 类 模板 实例化“c10::optional<std::vector<std::vector<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent,std::allocator<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent>>,std::allocator<std::vector<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent,std::allocator<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent>>>>>”的引用
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(387): warning C4624: “c10::trivially_copyable_optimization_optional_base<T>”: 已将析构函数隐式定义为“已删除”
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<std::vector<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent,std::allocator<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent>>,std::allocator<std::vector<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent,std::allocator<torch::autograd::profiler::LegacyEvent>>>>
        ]
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(181): warning C4624: “c10::constexpr_storage_t<T>”: 已将析构函数隐式定义为“已删除”
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<at::Tensor,std::allocator<at::Tensor>>
        ]
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(361): note: 查看对正在编译的 类 模板 实例化“c10::constexpr_storage_t<T>”的引用
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<at::Tensor,std::allocator<at::Tensor>>
        ]
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(418): note: 查看对正在编译的 类 模板 实例化“c10::trivially_copyable_optimization_optional_base<T>”的引用
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<at::Tensor,std::allocator<at::Tensor>>
        ]
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(418): note: 查看对正在编译的 别名 模板 实例化“c10::OptionalBase<std::vector<at::Tensor,std::allocator<at::Tensor>>>”的引用
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\torch\csrc\api\include\torch/optim/lbfgs.h(44): note: 查看对正在编译的 类 模板 实例化“c10::optional<std::vector<at::Tensor,std::allocator<at::Tensor>>>”的引用
K:\pytorchModel\libtorch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(387): warning C4624: “c10::trivially_copyable_optimization_optional_base<T>”: 已将析构函数隐式定义为“已删除”
        with
        [
            T=std::vector<at::Tensor,std::allocator<at::Tensor>>
        ]
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: “"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"”: 返回代码“0x2”
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: “"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"”: 返回代码“0x2”
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: “"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"”: 返回代码“0x2”
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: “"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"”: 返回代码“0x2”
Stop.
```

why is that? Is there a problem with my CmakeLists.txt configuration?

Comment: According to the very first [C4067 warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4067?view=msvc-160) - "unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline" - your Visual Studio doesn't understand some features used in the header `c10/macros/Macros.h`. What version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2019  Is my version too high?

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the error NMAKE: fatal error U1077. It turns out that libTorch is introduced in QT and needs to be introduced in front of qt.